# How to stop ObjectFactory regenerating every clean with maven

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

Im using **jaxb2-maven-plugin** to generate my web service sources from a WSDL. It works fine,  but I have a little problem and it is that everytime I do a clean with maven, the class **ObjectFactory.java** is regenerated changing it's methods order.

Looking on the internet I found that there is an issue opened with this [error](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-598), however there is no solution yet.

I was wondering if anyone has faced this problem and found a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you *want* to delete the ObjectFactory each time?  If you don't care about that, just skip deleting that class by using this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#filesets  Let me know if that's a solution for you and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @tieTYT thanks for your answer. I don't want to delete it, I just want to keep the existing ObjectFactory. I have all my generated files in my repository, and everytime I clean the project with maven it shows changes in this file, however it's the same file but with its methods in different order.

Comment: I looked into it and this is a really tough problem to solve because the maven-clean-plugin will always delete the target directory.  The best advice I could give is to generate these files in another project.  That way you don't have to clean it for unrelated reasons, only when you really do need to change things.  But, that will just lessen the problem, not fix it.

Comment: @tieTYT we thought about it, but we have several web services and we don't want to have an individual JAR for each of them. I guess we will have to live with it untill the plugin is fixed. Thanks anyway for your time :)